# Parse Error - When convering a xmlstring to a document

Tags: parsing

Been breaking my head to get this straight. Pretty simple though.. have not been able to figure out why. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here my XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <User mode="Retrieve" simCardNumber=“9602875089237652" softwareVersion=“9" phoneManufacturer=“Nokia" phoneModel="I747" deviceId=“562372389498734" networkOperator=“Blu">
     <Errors>
      <Error number="404"/>
    </Errors>
    </User>

    private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {    
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
        try 
        { 
            DocumentBuilder builder =factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
          //The below statement fails and jumps to return null                
         //Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr))); 
         //Adding replace method on the string to handle the strange looking double quote on the xml string. However I still get the same error.
         Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr.replace("“", "\'\""))));
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the quotes..

```
networkOperator=“Blu"
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. Did try out your suggestion; still ain't working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it isn't a paste error but you used “ instead of " in your code. The first one if often used in rich text editors as a starting quote, you need to change it manually to let it be parseable.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Did try out your suggestion; still ain't working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this solution works. Thanks everyone for your time and support.

```
      Document doc = null;
        try 
        { 
            DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlStr));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        return doc;
```